# javascript/jquery doesn't work in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have php page "Home.php", that present user posts(using ajax).
This is how I get the posts:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadmore()
    {
      var val = document.getElementById("result_no").value;
      var userval = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
      $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'fetch.php',
      data: {
        getresult:val,
        getuserid:userval
      },
      success: function (response) {
        var content = document.getElementById("result_para");
        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;

        // We increase the value by 2 because we limit the results by 2
        document.getElementById("result_no").value = Number(val)+10;
      }
      });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="result_para">


        </div>
    </div>
```

In every post, there is a like button(which also uses ajax). This is how I save the likes:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function likethis(likepostid)
                {


                      $.ajax({
                      type: 'post',
                      url: 'fetchlikes.php',
                      data: {
                        getpostid:likepostid
                      },
                      success: function (response) {

                      }
                      });
                  } 
            </script>
```

Before I used ajax to present posts, all worked well. But now when I press the like button, it DOES save the like, BUT the javascript/jquery doesn't work. I tried to make alert when I pressed the LIKE button, but it didn't work.

This is the index.js code(the javascript). It add +1 likes, when the user press the button:

```
$('.btn-counter_likecount').on('click', function(event, count) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //alert("hello");
  var $this = $(this),
      count = $this.attr('data-count'),
      active = $this.hasClass('active'),
      multiple = $this.hasClass('multiple-count_likecount');

  $.fn.noop = $.noop;
  $this.attr('data-count', ! active || multiple ? ++count : --count  )[multiple ? 'noop' : 'toggleClass']('active');
});
```

EDIT fetchlikes.php:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('blabla');

  $postid=$_POST['getpostid'];

  mysql_query("UPDATE user_post SET likes_count=likes_count+1 WHERE post_id='$postid'");

?>
```

Comment: Whats inside of your fetchlikes.php ? Edit your question please.

Comment: Your php code for `fetch.php` would definitely help. That way we can see what is being returned by your script and how your javascript/php interaction works. Right now we can only guess from the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your posts are being loaded dynamically, the javascript where you bind the event is running *before* the posts are actually loaded, thus the buttons don't exist when you try to bind the event. You can use delegated events in jQuery to handle this.

Your previous code

```
$('.btn-counter_likecount').on('click', function(event, count) {
  ....
});
```

New Code

```
$('#result-para').on('click','.btn-counter_likecount',function(event, count) {
  ....
}
```

This way the event will actually be bound to a parent element that already exists when jQuery's `ready()` function runs. This way, the event handler checks for matching elements when the event is *fired* rather than when the event is *bound*.

For further reading, look into [jQuery's delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)